# How to read JSON {"success": true} in Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

In normal `JSONObject jsonResponse`, I simply use `boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");` . Now, I am required to use Retrofit library.
I know that the response is in GSON format. That's why I'm having a hard time figuring out how to deal with the `$response["success"]` in my `php` file.

I tried this:

```
   call.enqueue(new Callback<User_Account_Model>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User_Account_Model> call, Response<User_Account_Model> response) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response));
                boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(success),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but what's inside the `try and catch` seems not to be executed. No Toast messages showing. Is my method correct and just missing something or it's completely wrong?

Comment: Please add `User_Account_Model` class also add log if any.

Comment: User_Account_Model only contains string email and password. the log doesn't show any important details to be used in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a Class with only one boolean value

```
public class MyResponse{
  @SerializedName("success")
  private boolean success;

  public boolean getSuccess(){
   return success; 
  }
  public void setSuccess(boolean _success){
   success = _success
  }

}
```

Use this class in enqueue method.

```
   call.enqueue(new Callback<MyResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<MyResponse> call, Response<MyResponse> response) {

        try {
              int statusCode = response.code();
              Log.d("Response Code: ", "status Code: " + statusCode);
              if (response.isSuccessful()){
                MyResponse mResponse = response.body();
              }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If you response only contain one node "success" then it will work.

Comment: how can I get boolean success if getSuccess() isn't called?. same as mResponse.

Comment: use this -> boolean success = mResponse.getSuccess();

Comment: thanks! it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add key in `User_Account_Model` for `success` like

```
public class User_Account_Model{
    @Expose
    private boolean success;

    // Add Getter and setter for **success**
}
```

Now in `onResponse` method add like

```
try {
    String json =response.body().string();
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(json);
    boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,String.valueOf(success),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: so what's the use of getSuccess?